# bootstrap (AdminLTE) file upload wizard not showing uploaded filename in the checkbox

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I am trying to develop a dashboard using the AdminLTE-3.0.5 starter template. I programmed to upload a file in the sidebar, but the uploaded filename is not shown in the box provided. If I hover mouse on the box I can see the uploaded filename in the tooltip text.
The modified starter page is shown below. What am I missing?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>test dash</title>

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light" style="background-color: #383c44;">
      <!-- Left navbar links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"
              style="color:#d6d7d8"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.navbar -->

    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
      <!-- Brand Logo -->
      <a href="#" class="brand-link">
        <img src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo"
          class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8">
        <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Dashboard</span>
      </a>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
            <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-closed">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                <!-- <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> -->
                <p>
                  data analysis
                  <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </p>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <div class="custom-file mb-2 mt-2">
                    <!-- <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename2" style="color:#d6d7d8"> -->
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                  </div>
                  <script>
                    // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
                    $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
                      var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                      $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
                    });
                  </script>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
      <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <h4 class="m-0 text-dark">Selected Columns</h4>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.content-header -->

      <!-- Main content -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Box 1</h5>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Box 2</h5>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.card -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
      <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
      <div class="p-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->

    <!-- Main Footer -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <!-- To the right -->
      <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline">
        Anything you want
      </div>
      <!-- Default to the left -->
      <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2019 <a href="https://adminlte.io">AdminLTE.io</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->

  <!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following required scripts that were provided at the bottom of the body should have been in the head section.

```
  <!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="./AdminLTE-3.0.5/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to import this

```
<script src=".AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/bs-custom-file-input/bs-custom-file-input.min.js"></script>
```

and this code to initialize

```
<script>
$(function () {
  bsCustomFileInput.init();
});
</script>
```